# ASP.NET Azure webapp frequently redirects to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, timeout

I have an ASP.NET azure web app. In recent times, the user is being redirected to login page very frequently, even while performing back-to-back actions. When I checked the log file, there are many "Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired." errors logged.

The app uses 1 instance (of 1 core, 1.75 GB RAM) and never exceed 30% of memory consumption so far. I assume there is no issue with MachineKey in this case. The part of web.config is as below:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="10" />
</authentication>
```

Since it is in production, I am little hesitant to move to SQL or Redis storage, unless the storage is the culprit. Is there anything else I can check to corner the problem? or am I missing a setting or two?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the slidingExpiration property to true for Forms tag

```
 <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="10"  slidingExpiration=true />
```

The slidingExpiration make sure that the timer is reset after each request otherwise even if the user is active the user will be logged out after the timeout expiry.

Comment: Thanks, I am checking with this setting now. Will post results soon.